# When using Public-Accessible S3 buckets, how are there not collisions with other Public-Accessible S3 bucket and object names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket `my-bucket` and an object in that bucket `my-image.jpg`

In order to display these images in a website, directly out of S3, I've put this  bucket policy on `my-bucket`:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, in my website, I can conveniently just do this in my HTML:

```
<img width="400" height="400" 
            src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/my-image.jpg">
```

**But what is stopping someone, somewhere, from making their own public `my-bucket`, and adding a `my-image.jpg`?** How will it load the proper image? Does S3 handle this in some way?

**note** No, these are not the actual bucket names + image names. They are examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Amazon's Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/CreatingABucket.html):

> The bucket name you choose must be unique across all existing bucket names in Amazon S3.

So Amazon won't let you have a naming collision in the first place.

I think that is now per *region*, since regions get their own domain, but I am not sure.

Comment: yep, turns out `my-bucket` (not surprisingly) is an existing S3 bucket. When I try to make it in my own console, I get an error saying that it already exists. Thanks, Lorenzo!